# variable font formatting

Tags: formatting, strings, variable

I would like to create a LaTeX function that: (1) takes a string as an argument (2) calculates the length of the string, (3) divides the length by 3, (3) applies one type of formatting to the first 1/3 of the string, another formatting to the middle 1/3 of the string, and then another formatting to the remaining part of the string.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what should happen if the string is "iiiixxxxmmmm" (assuming a non-proportional font)?

Answer (score 2):

The following is an approach using the `fp` package for calculations and the `xstring` package for string splitting. The formatting commands are hard-coded, in this case bold, blue, and Large font.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\divprint}[1]{%
\StrLen{#1}[\mylen]% get length of string
\FPeval\x{clip(round(\mylen/3,0))}% divide by 3, round on 0 decimal places, clip any trailing zeroes
\StrSplit{#1}{\x}{\strA}{\strBC}% split string on the calculated position
\StrSplit{\strBC}{\x}{\strB}{\strC}% split remaining string
\textbf{\strA}\textcolor{blue}{\strB}\Large\strC\normalsize% print formatted string
}
\begin{document}
\divprint{fourfourfour}

\divprint{random string}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]